# How to filter on each array returned by an observable of arrays

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a method that returns devices and I can see it returns 2 devices:

```
public getDevices(): Observable<Array<Device>> {
  return this.state$
    .pipe(
      map((devices: Array<Device>) => {
        return devices
      })
    );
}
```

But if I add a filter on the array items then it displays no devices at all:

```
public getDevices(): Observable<Array<Device>> {
  return this.state$
    .pipe(
      map((devices: Array<Device>) => {
        return devices
          .filter((device: Device) => {
            return device != null && device.mute != true
          })
      }),
    );
}
```

The same for an hard coded true filter:

```
public getDevices(): Observable<Array<Device>> {
  return this.state$
    .pipe(
      map((devices: Array<Device>) => {
        return devices
          .filter((device: Device) => {
            return true
          })
      }),
    );
}
```

I also tried with the following and still it displays no devices:

```
public getDevices(): Observable<Array<Device>> {
  return this.state$
    .pipe(
      map((devices: Array<Device>) => {
        devices = devices.filter((device: Device) => {
          return device != null && device.mute != true
        })
        return devices;
      }),
    );
}
```

This shows non empty arrays in the logger:

```
public getDevices(): Observable<Array<Device>> {
  return this.state$
    .pipe(
      tap((devices: Array<Device>) => {
        console.log(devices);
      }),
      // map((devices: Array<Device>) => {
      //   return devices
      //     .filter((device: Device) => {
      //       return device != null && device.mute != true
      //     })
      // }),
    );
}
```

The browser console content:

```
(2) [Device, Device]
0: Device
id: "MidiThroughPort-0"
name: "Midi Through Port-0"
mute: false
midiMessageSubscription: Subscriber {closed: false, _parentOrParents: null, _subscriptions: Array(1), syncErrorValue: null, syncErrorThrown: false, …}
synth: s.default.PolySynth {_context: s.d…t.Context, output: s.d…t.Volume, _volume: s.d…t.Volume, volume: s.d…t.Param, _scheduledEvents: Array(0), …}
keyboard: Piano {_events: {…}, _maxListeners: undefined, type: "Piano", parent: div#keyboard-device-MidiThroughPort-0, width: 500, …}
__proto__: Object
1: Device {id: "VMPKOutput", name: "VMPK Output", mute: false, midiMessageSubscription: Subscriber, synth: s.d…t.PolySynth, …}
length: 2
```

But uncommenting the commented out code as in:

```
public getDevices(): Observable<Array<Device>> {
  return this.state$
    .pipe(
      tap((devices: Array<Device>) => {
        console.log(devices);
      }),
      map((devices: Array<Device>) => {
        return devices
          .filter((device: Device) => {
            return device != null && device.mute != true
          })
      }),
    );
}
```

makes the logger, yes the very same logger, now show an empty array: `[]`

The one very strange thing is that, when I comment the filter code, the logger is called only once, a one time empty `[]`
And when I uncomment the filter code, the above logger is called 5 times, a first time empty `[]` and then 4 times non empty `(2) [Device, Device]`

Here is how I add a device:

```
public addDevice(device: Device) {
  const index = this.getDeviceIndex(device.id);
  if (index === -1) {
    device.id = this.commonService.normalizeName(device.id);
    this.getState().push(device);
  }
}
```

with the state being:

```
export class Store<T> {

  state$: Observable<T>;
  private _state$: BehaviorSubject<T>;

  protected constructor(initialState: T) {
    this._state$ = new BehaviorSubject(initialState);
    this.state$ = this._state$.asObservable();
  }

  public getState(): T {
    return this._state$.getValue();
  }

  public setState(nextState: T) {
    this._state$.next(nextState);
  }

}
```

UPDATE: The observable was not notified of any change when push another item to its array value. So I created another method in the `Store` class that reloads the observable:

```
public reloadState() {
  this._state$.next(this._state$.getValue());
}
```

I call this method after pushing another item in the devices array:

```
public addDevice(device: Device) {
  const index = this.getDeviceIndex(device.id);
  if (index === -1) {
    device.id = this.commonService.normalizeName(device.id);
    this.getState().push(device);
    this.reloadState();
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you `console.log(devices)` before you apply the filter

Comment: devices.filter(device => device != null && device.mute != true)

Comment: @ajrthegreat This is the same as the last example?

Comment: Because `Array.prototype.filter` returns a new array with values fitting the filter condition, the first example with the filter should work. Are you sure that the devices you're returning fits the condition you're setting? If you use the `tap` operator to `console.log` the devices, can you see that they're not null and that their mute property is not true?

Comment: What is the output of the console.log?

Comment: most of the times, filter doesn't work whan you try to use it on an object (with key/values) instead of an array. Are you sure `devices` is a javascript array ?

Comment: I edited the question to add the console log output.

Comment: With the filter, the logger is called only once, a one time empty [] Without the filter code, the logger is called 5 times, a first time empty: [] and then 4 times non empty: (2) [Device, Device] It is called only once in the first case as the observable content is not being modified, thus, not liable to report any changes.

Comment: Can you recreate this in a minimal stackblitz?

Comment: @AndrewAllen I took this to mean that `T` in this case is `Device[]`.

Comment: @AndrewAllen You were onto something as I now see the `.push()` call does not let know the observable that its array value has changed. So I created another `reloadState` method in the `Store` class that triggers a reload of the observable. I updated the question with this.

Comment: @Stephane aren't you better off just setting a new version of the array that includes the new item?

Comment: I've tried everything I could think of...I can't replicate a `tap(console.log)` which returns `[Device, Device]` be affected by the `map(arr => arr.filter(d=>true))`.[stackblitz, if you want to try and replicate](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-16prrc). Perhaps (and I've done this) the map showhow ended up inside the tap??

Comment: @Andrew Allen I'm not sure about what show how you mean, but the tap has no side effect, I added it way later, and the issue remains when I remove it.

Comment: @Kurt I prefer to keep my method has its name is more explicit and shows the original intent. But you are right, I did try successfully with a state setter too, but chose not to keep it.

Comment: @Stephane Any chance of a stackblitz yet? There's not much point keeping this question open without some form of demo

Comment: @KurtHamilton I did a stackblitz at https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tbouxt but I'm having trouble with some import statements.

Comment: @KurtHamilton The filter was working fine. I reckon I was facing a race condition. When doing an explicit `this.reloadState();` call in adding a device, the devices showed up fine even with the filter on. Without the filter the devices didn't need the explicit `this.reloadState();` call to show up. I suppose there is a design flaw in my central data store. With a working stackblitz we should pinpoint that.

Comment: As a side note, I also had to then use the `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` in the component.

Comment: @Stephane https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vrqkqv. So obviously your original design doesn't work with complex objects such as arrays because you're only modifying the internal state. You *have* to either set the value to be a new array or manually call something like `reloadState`. I'm not exactly sure what the problem is here.

Comment: @KurtHamilton I copied your stackblitz project into a locally run one so see if I'd get the same success, and yes it works fine also on my dev machine. If you are inclined to, feel free to clone my code at https://github.com/stephaneeybert/midi-lib

Comment: I'm not quite *that* interested! Although it does remind me of an app I created a few years ago that allowed me to create multi-instrument tablature and play back the audio. I should definitely revisit it in Angular.... Good luck!